# How to add custom labels to a torchdata datapipe?

Tags: python, torch, pytorch-datapipe, torchdata

I am trying to load image data for model training from a self-hosted S3 storage (MinIO). Pytorch provides [new datapipes with this functionality in the torchdata library](https://pytorch.org/data/beta/generated/torchdata.datapipes.iter.S3FileLoader.html#torchdata.datapipes.iter.S3FileLoader).

So within my function to create the datapipe, I have these lines:

```
dp_s3 = IterableWrapper(list(sample_dict.keys()))
dp_s3 = dp_s3.load_files_by_s3()
dp_s3 = dp_s3.map(open_image)
dp_s3 = dp_s3.map(transform)
```

The problem with this approach is, that the S3 file loader datapipe returns a tuple of a string, which contains the file path on the S3 storage as label and `io.BytesIO` containing the image data. However I have all labels and the files to load in a separate text files, which are loaded into `sample_dict` (a dictionary mapping file paths to classification labels) in a previous step.

Question is now, how can I get the labels from `sample_dict` into my mapping functions?
There seem to be two main obstacles to achieve this:

- The dataloader is multi-threaded and I get a pickle error if I add `sample_dict` to it. Also I cannot make the dictionary globally accessible for other worker threads which are handled by pytorch
- `load_files_bys3()` is the functional name for `S3FileLoader` which can only deal with S3 type file paths as input. My initial though was that I need to us a map-style datapipe for this instead of a iterable-style, but unfortunately there are no map-style S3 datapipes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer by using just plain and simple `functool.partial` and use that to map my function with `sample_dict` as fixed input:

```
dp_s3 = IterableWrapper(list(sample_dict.keys()))
dp_s3 = dp_s3.load_files_by_s3()
map_function = partial(map_labels, sample_dict)
dp_s3 = dp_s3.to_map_datapipe(map_function)
```

and

```
def map_labels(sample_dict, inputs):
    # do stuff here
```

I have still have to test this before marking the question as answered, but initial debugging look promising.

Additionally, there is already a [open feature request on the torchdata repo](https://github.com/pytorch/data/issues/802) which seems to address this problem as well.